# to enable or disable the notification flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to enable/disable the notification service with help of a button when this button is enabled, the user receives the notification, and when it's disabled he won't receive any notifications.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class FirebaseNotifications {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging;

  void setUpFirebase() {
    _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();

  }

  void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();

    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print(token);
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
  }

  void iOS_Permission() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

what you should do is that when implementing the notifications subscribe the user to a topic with

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic ('news');
```

If this user wants to deactivate notifications, you only unsubscribe from the topic with

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic ('news');
```

Obviously when you send the notifications from the backend or console, you must specify this topic "news" or the name that you decide to put it